# How to filter element depending on the previous element in an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, ecmascript-6

Let's say you have the following code to filter animals in order only to save those that have more weight than the previous animal in the array (the first object will never be saved since there is no previous animal):

```js
    const animals = [
        { id: 3, weight: 300, type: 'pig' },
        { id: 1, weight: 200, type: "cow" },
        { id: 7, weight: 400, type: "horse" },
        { id: 6, weight: 100, type: "pig" },
    ];


const filteredAnimals = animals.filter((animal, index) => 
    animals[index - 1] && animal.weight > animals[index - 1].weight);

console.log('filtered animals: ', filteredAnimals);
```

This works as expected, but I cannot figure out how to apply the same filter having an array of arrays:

```
const animals = [
    [
        { id: 5, weight: 300, type: 'pig' },
        { id: 1, weight: 200, type: "cow" },
        { id: 3, weight: 400, type: "horse" },
        { id: 4, weight: 350, type: "pig" },
    ],
    [
        { id: 2, weight: 250, type: "horse" },
        { id: 6, weight: 350, type: 'pig' },
        { id: 8, weight: 250, type: "cow" },
        { id: 7, weight: 400, type: "pig" },
    ]
]
```

In this case, the expected result should be:

```
const filteredAnimals = [
    [
        { id: 3, weight: 400, type: "horse" },
    ],
    [
        { id: 6, weight: 350, type: "pig" },
        { id: 7, weight: 400, type: "pig" },
    ]
]
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just surround your `filter` in a `.map`, to iterate over all sub-arrays:

```js
const animals = [
    [
        { id: 5, weight: 300, type: 'pig' },
        { id: 1, weight: 200, type: "cow" },
        { id: 3, weight: 400, type: "horse" },
        { id: 4, weight: 350, type: "pig" },
    ],
    [
        { id: 2, weight: 250, type: "horse" },
        { id: 6, weight: 350, type: 'pig' },
        { id: 8, weight: 250, type: "cow" },
        { id: 7, weight: 400, type: "pig" },
    ]
]


const filteredAnimals = animals.map(
  subarr => subarr.filter((animal, index) => 
    subarr[index - 1] && animal.weight > subarr[index - 1].weight
  )
);
console.log(filteredAnimals);
```